# How to add index to label in DSE graph?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise-graph

I turned off the auto scan for dse graph and add index for properties of vertices and edges. All my query failed with the following error message,

```
g.V().hasLabel("PERMISSIONS").valueMap()
```

yields,

```
Could not find an index on vertices labelled 'PERMISSIONS' to answer the condition: '((label = PERMISSIONS))'. Current indexes are: byName(Secondary)->name. Alternatively if in development enable graph scan by using graph.allow_scan. Graph scan is NOT suitable for anything other than toy graphs.
```

How to add index to lable?

Answer (score 0):

The docs have a section on indexing which will show you how to create an index - http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/indexingTOC.html

It looks like though that you are trying to return all data for the Permissions Vertex Label.  That would cause a cluster scan.  Are you able to filter your query by a property, instead of trying to return all data?

Comment: the dataset if the vertices are fixed so there is no filter.